# How can I display a system message in Smali?

Tags: smali

I'm trying to display a default system alert message in slime, but it's not working..

Here's what I have tried:

```
.line 41
invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljavax/security/cert/X509Certificate;->getPublicKey()Ljava/security/PublicKey;

const/4 v0, 0x1
const-string v1, Ljavax/security/cert/X509Certificate;->getPublicKey()Ljava/security/PublicKey; # i have also tried a normal double quotes "string"
invoke-static {p0, v1, v0}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->makeText(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;
move-result-object v0
invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V
```

It compiles successfully but when I try to run the app it crashes.

Comment: Did you look at the stack trace and error message of the crash?

Comment: What's this line in your code: `const-string v1, Ljavax/security/cert/X509Certificate;->getPublicKey()Ljava/security/PublicKey;` ? Calling an instance method inside `const-string` instruction?

Comment: Good point Mehran Torki. That wouldn't even compile.